# Is it possible to send data at a certain speed (x items per second)

Tags: python

(Just wanted to mention that this is my first question and I apologize if I did something wrong). I am making a Python program that parses a CSV file and saves it as a list. However, the program takes user input as to how fast they want to send that data to a server. How would I regulate how fast the data is sent (ie. 100 items / second etc.) I am using PyQt5 for the GUI front end and the CSV module to parse the file. For testing purposes, I am sending the data to another CSV that the Python script writes.

I have tried sleep and date and time but since reading/writing data is not instant, it won't be x items / 1 second. I wasn't really able to find any documentation but I feel like date and time could still be viable although I really don't know how since I am a beginner.

I would like the program to read the CSV file and write/send it to another file at a certain rate/second. I have only had the program write it at normal speed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You create a queue where you drop the data items in and a thread that consumes the items from the queue and waits some time after each is sent. You might have to compensate the sending time when calculating the wait time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KlausD says, you can do something in a thread and use a queue if you want to do processing in between sends.  But you might want to just do your sending in a loop in the main thread.  How you loop over the items and delay so that you're sending them at the right rate should be pretty independent of how your code will actually be structured.

Rather than worry about what the delays are in advance that will contribute to your send rate, what you want to do is adaptively delay.  So you figure out how long it actually took to do the send, and then you delay for whatever the remaining time is that you want to wait before doing another send.  If your primary goal is your average send rate rather than the actual delay between two sends, which I would think would be the case, then you just want to be looking at how long it's taken you to send items so far in relation to how many things you've sent.  From this you can adaptively delay to pretty much exactly adjust the overall send time to what you want.  Over hundreds or thousands of sends, you can guarantee a rate that is pretty much exactly what your user has asked for.  Here's an example of how to do that, abstracting away any sending of data to just a `print()` statement and a random delay:

```
import time
import random

# Send this many items per second
sends_per_second = 10

# Simulate send time by introducing a random delay of at most this many seconds
max_item_delay_seconds = .06

# How many items to send
item_count = 100

# Do something representing a send, introducing a random delay
def do_one_item(i):
    time.sleep(random.random() * max_item_delay_seconds)
    print("Sent item {}".format(i))

# Record the starting time
start_time = time.time()

# For each item to send...
for i in range(item_count):

    # Send the item
    do_one_item(i)

    # Compute how much time we've spent so far
    time_spent = time.time() - start_time

    # Compute how much time we want to have spent so far based on the desired send rate
    should_time = (i + 1) / sends_per_second

    # If we're going too fast, wait just long enough to get us back on track
    if should_time > time_spent:
        print("Delaying {} seconds".format(should_time - time_spent))
        time.sleep(should_time - time_spent)

time_spent = time.time() - start_time
print("Sent {} items in {} seconds ({} items per second)".format(item_count, time_spent, item_count / time_spent))
```

Abbreviated output:

```
Sent item 0
Delaying 0.06184182167053223 seconds
Sent item 1
Delaying 0.0555738925933838 seconds
...
Sent item 98
Delaying 0.036808872222900746 seconds
Sent item 99
Delaying 0.03746294975280762 seconds
Sent 100 items in 10.000335931777954 seconds (9.999664079506683 items per second)
```

As you can see, despite the code introducing a random delay for each send, and the delay logic therefore having to compute delays that are all over the place, the actual send rate achieved is exactly what was asked for to 5 or so decimal places.

You can play with the numbers in this example.  You should be able to convince yourself that unless each send takes too long to keep up with your requested rate, you can dial in any send rate you want with this sort of logic. You can also see that you add too much simulated delay to represent the send time so that you can't keep up with the desired rate, you will get no delay calls and the code will just send items as fast as it can.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and definitely a better way to approach the issue. I would just like to clarify that this method when sending, let's say 200 items per second, will roughly space the 200 items over the single second or will it send the 200 items in a quarter second and then wait for .75 seconds before sending the next batch. I think that the distinction might make an impact when working with servers although I'll have to ask what my lead thinks about on the issue. Thank you once again.

Comment: After working through the code and employing it within my program, it makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your question before now.  You've probably figured it out, but it delays between every send, so there's no batching.  You could certainly add an inner loop if you did want to do batching, and just do the rate regulation in the outer loop.